# Vue.js sort array let page jump to top

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I want to add a new item to list in vue, that's my code (fixed this, look at edit):

```
this.stops.push(newStopObject)
```

But if I push the stop object the page jumps to the top of the page. I want it to stay at the last position. If I remove a item from the list, the page stays at the same position. So its only happening if I add something. The list rendered is a custom component like so:

```
<template v-for="(stop, index) in stops">
    <Stop props...></stop>
    <anotherComponent></anotherComponent>
</template>
```

This is my Quasar form

```
 <q-form
              @submit="onAddEntry"
              class="q-gutter-md addEntryForm"
              ref="addEntryForm"
            >
              <q-input
                filled
                v-model="date"
                error-message="Bitte gib ein richtiges Datum an"
                :error="!isDateTimeValid()"
                lazy-rules
                bottom-slots
                style="width:300px"
                class="input-item"
                outlined
              >
                <template v-slot:prepend>
                  <q-icon
                    name="event"
                    class="cursor-pointer"
                  >
                    <q-popup-proxy
                      transition-show="scale"
                      transition-hide="scale"
                    >
                      <q-date
                        v-model="date"
                        today-btn
                        mask="DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm"
                      />
                      <!--  :options="dateOptions" -->
                    </q-popup-proxy>
                  </q-icon>
                </template>

                <template v-slot:append>
                  <q-icon
                    name="access_time"
                    class="cursor-pointer"
                  >
                    <q-popup-proxy
                      transition-show="scale"
                      transition-hide="scale"
                    >
                      <q-time
                        v-model="date"
                        mask="DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm"
                        format24h
                      />
                    </q-popup-proxy>
                  </q-icon>
                </template>
              </q-input>         
              <div>
                <q-btn
                  round
                  color="primary"
                  icon="add"
                  type="submit"
                >
                  <q-tooltip>
                    Stopp hinzufügen
                  </q-tooltip>
                </q-btn>
              </div>
            </q-form>
```

The onAdddEntry method adds the item to the list.

**Update**
If found out, when splicing the new item into the array it works!
But there is another cause for the same problem. After I added the item, I want to sort it with this code here:

```
this.stops.sort(this.compare)
```

Compare method is this here:

```
compare (a, b) {
  const initDateA = this.getDateFromString(a.InitDate)
  const initDateB = this.getDateFromString(b.InitDate)

  if (initDateA > initDateB) return 1
  if (initDateB > initDateA) return -1

  return 0
}
```

Here it also jumps to top of the page. If I remove sorting, it works now.

**Update**
I found out if the new element is at the last position of the array it doesn't work, but if its on any other position it works, even with sorting enabled.

Comment: Can you add the code that handles the clicks? it may be that you are inadvertently telling the browser to scroll to the top...

Comment: I uncommented all the code except the push of the new stop object. But the method is called on submit of a quasar form.

Comment: @Marco please share the code of that quasar form

Comment: Try to add the prevent modifier like `@submit.prevent="onAddEntry"`

Comment: I added it, but its unfortunately still jumping to top